# Using the same dll in a web service and a client application

Tags: c#, web-services, dll

I'm updating a few web services that have some components in common, so I thought that by creating a library that has that code in it, it could ease maintenance. When using a class from said library, the web service forces me to call the method with its proxy class.

Since the system is somewhat old, I can't change the architecture. The compilation is made in x64. I've already attempted to change the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies".

Referencing a class "x" from the "y" library on a web service "w" forces me to use the class "w.x" instead of "y.x" on a service method call.

Best regards,
Fábio Jesus

The code that I can provide is the following:

**Library**

```
namespace Library1
{
   public class Class1
   {
   }
}
```

**Service**

```
namespace Services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface Service
    {
       [OperationContract]
       void Method(Library1.Class1 cc);
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
namespace Client
{
   public class ClientControl : PageControl
   {
      public void Execute(){
         using(var _service = new Services.Service){
            var cc = new Library1.Class1();
            _service.Method(cc);
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you provide a minimal working example of your issue?

Comment: I need to send the object as the dll's type instead of the service's proxy type.
I've imported the same dll into the client and service. Whenever I instantiate a [Library].Class1 object and send it through the service's method the error "cannot convert from [Library].Class1 to [Service].Class1".
I hope the following example helps:

Service _service = new Service();
ClassLibrary1.Class1 cc = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
_service.Method(cc);

Comment: When _service.Method(cc) doesn't take an Interface and you do not have access to the source code than you can't do much. The only thing you could try is to inherit from the type _service.Method(..) expects and overload what you need, and then pass your inherited class.

Comment: I apologize if there's something that's not clear, but I haven't seen this issue elsewhere, and this is my first time working with web services. The service's interface for the method is the following:
`[OperationContract]
void Method(ClassLibrary1.Class1 cc);`

Comment: Can you edit your Question and add the related code as an example. Maybe than it's easier to help.